# Azure B2C - Multiple Reply Url

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I created a Native Client App with Web/WebAPI in Azure B2C

I want to add multiple reply urls with the same domains for testing and qa etc.

e.g.

https://site.domain.com 
https://site-qa.domain.com/

But got error:
Cannot update Application: One of the reply URLs provided for application 'My App' is on a domain different from other reply URL(s). Plese make sure all reply URLs other than localhost are on the same root domain.

Also note: 'Plese' is miss-spelled

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be an issue, I have created a request on the [feedback portal](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/16692610-aadb2c-add-multiply-reply-urls-with-the-same-doma).
You can vote it and wait for the Development Team to fix it.

[Update]: As explained in the updated [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#restrictions-on-redirect-urls) about restrictions on redirect URIs, there is a quick workaround: first add the domain as a redirect URI and then add the sub-domains, like so:

- https://example.com
- https://client1.example.com
- https://client2.example.com

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Unfortunately, the link to the updated [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-limitations#restrictions-on-redirect-uris) does not work anymore:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-limitations#restrictions-on-redirect-uris