# Azure AD B2C reply url to wildcard URL

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am using Azure 'B2C', and users are creating successfully in B2C. And I am using dynamic web apps. ie, there is number of web apps are present.

```
sssss01.example.com
sss2.example.com
wwwss2.example.com........
```

When a user want to login using B2C, it's successfully login, but it reply url is not correct. I checked in azure, B2C app not supporting wildcard(*). So Is there any option to add wildcard, or any other method to manage pragmatically ?
Sign in reply url is different  for different web apps.

Answer (score 3):

Wildcard redirect URLs are not supported in OAuth2. See: [why are redirect URLs fully qualified](http://Wildcard%20redirect%20URLs%20are%20not%20supported%20in%20OAuth2.%20See%20this%20post:%20why%20are%20redirect%20URLs%20fully%20qualified.%20%20And,%20unfortunately,%20we%20can't%20manage%20B2C%20programmatically.%20%20UserVoice%20item:%20Programmatically%20manage%20B2C%20policies).

Unfortunately, we can't manage B2C programmatically.

You can upvote this item on User Voice and subscribe to stay updated: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory

Others have suggested this same feature but the User Voice forum appears to be down right now.

Comment: Is there any other option like dynamically add reply urls in B2C app ?

Comment: No, but you can kind of work around this using subdomains. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123640/azure-b2c-multiple-reply-url

Comment: In the case of known subdomain its ok. But after creating the website, then only we know the subdomain URL. In the case of the AD, we can add a reply URL like https://*.domain.com. But in B2C we can't create like this. Any other option to add unknown subdomain names as reply urls?